# API array inside array to print to a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am building a program to print OpenSky-network api information. The api return array of airplanes information arrays. I am wondering how print the airplane information to a html table. See it return an Array of arrays. I'm trying to print the information in the second array to the table.

The code at the moment print the arrays to the columns.

CONSOLE LOG: [Console image return from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEt7K.png)

CURRENT RESULTS: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZ2Qw.png)
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/header.css' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script rel="script" src='/javascripts/displayData.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<%include templates/header.ejs%>
<table id="data">
    <tr>
        <th>ICAO24</th>
        <th>CountryOrigin</th>
        <th>longitude</th>
        <th>latitude</th>
        <th>altitude</th>
        <th>velocity m/s</th>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

````
const api_url = 'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=45.8389&lomin=5.9962&lamax=47.8229&lomax=10.5226';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get(api_url, function (data,status) {
        console.log(data.states);
            var states = (data.states);
            $.each(states, function () {
                $("#data").append('<tr><td>' + states[0] + '</td><td>' + data.states[2] + '</td><td>' + data.states[5] + '</td><td>' + data.states[6] + '</td><td>' + data.states[7] + '</td><td>' + data.states[9] + '</td></tr>')
            })
    })
}) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you iterate the `states` (`data.states`) array with `$.each()`, in the callback you use `data.states`, and not the current value (2nd param of `$.each()` - `state` in the example). Your code should be something like:

```js
const api_url = 'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=45.8389&lomin=5.9962&lamax=47.8229&lomax=10.5226';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get(api_url, function(data, status) {
    var states = (data.states);
    $.each(states, function(index, state) {
      $("#data").append('<tr><td>' + state[0] + '</td><td>' + state[2] + '</td><td>' + state[5] + '</td><td>' + state[6] + '</td><td>' + state[7] + '</td><td>' + state[9] + '</td></tr>')
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data">
  <tr>
    <th>ICAO24</th>
    <th>CountryOrigin</th>
    <th>longitude</th>
    <th>latitude</th>
    <th>altitude</th>
    <th>velocity m/s</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I would iterate the `states` with `Array.forEach()`, and use destructuring to extract the cols data. Combine all relevant cols to a single array.

To render use a template literal, and iterate the array of cols. For each column create a `td` element. Join the strings, and wrap with a `tr`.

```js
const api_url = 'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=45.8389&lomin=5.9962&lamax=47.8229&lomax=10.5226';
$(document).ready(() => {
  $.get(api_url, ({ states }, status) => {
    const $data = $("#data");

    // use forEach and destructure the columns data
    states.forEach(([col1, , col2, , , col3, col4, col5, , col6]) => {
      const cols = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6]; // combine to a single array

      $data.append(
        `<tr>${cols.map(c => `<td>${c}</td>`).join('')}</tr>` // iterate the cols and create the cells
      );
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data">
  <tr>
    <th>ICAO24</th>
    <th>CountryOrigin</th>
    <th>longitude</th>
    <th>latitude</th>
    <th>altitude</th>
    <th>velocity m/s</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you, much appreciated. It's working the way I wanted. Thanks